# Ruby or pry-nav bug? Debugging segmentation fault feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure what to think of a segfault I'fe run into in terms of whether this is a ruby bug, a rails bug or simply a problem with pry-nav and was hoping for some feedback to either know 
A) how to resolve it or 
B) where to report the issue.

I have reported the issue here: https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav/issues/8

The original context of this is that this is in a Rails app and specifically happens on a line where ActiveRecord is involved such as:
`variable = ARTableName.something.to_i`

So I'm supposing that this is evoking the entry into monitor.rb.

However from reading a bit more I'm wondering more seriously if it's not an issue with Ruby and would thus like to get some input as what may be really going on here more from more experienced eyes.

The actual crash report [from Mac OS X is also here](https://raw.github.com/gist/f79101a0a6ee287f20b4/0eff429f8e9eeb86d4d7e87ef20ece0febc33557/gistfile1.txt).

Comment: On closer inspection, I believe that this particular error and segfault is coming from a Mysql2::Error in a particular situation.  When that particular situation is removed then it will move on through the logic it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this with or without the wonderful [pry-stack_explorer](https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer) plugin installed as well?

EDIT: if you're just using pry-nav, then it's *definitely* a bug in either Ruby itself or an extension library -- pry-nav is pure ruby, and should never cause a segfault, no matter what it does.

Comment: Without pry-stack_explorer installed.

Comment: Also as a "bonus" @banister, it seems as though the `next` function works more akin to gdb step; is there a way to perform a `next` that steps over an instruction set vs drilling down into it as the prior is overkill in most cases for me right now and I'm not seeing an option to perform the latter.

Comment: next has always behaved like gdb's 'next' for me. However i think that pry-nav is a work in progress and will be significantly improved in the near future, stay tuned

Comment: for me right now when I hit next on an AR query it dives right down into the stack.  Should I be using another plugin other than -nav temporarily as I noticed there are a few others floating around that are older and not as up-to-date.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) as noted `mysql2` was seemingly the culprit in that when pry is used with a faulty query it produces the segfault. 2) `next` interestingly does seem to work correctly most of the time.  I found that having a `binding.pry` right next to a database query seems to cause it to just jump on past the rest of the method it's called in and then on into monitor.rb and then seemingly exits properly.  If I place the `binding.pry` after the query, things work seemingly perfectly.